# How to post mltipart form-data in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, multipartform-data

I am new to Angular 5 and needed some help with image upload. My current HTML form looks something like

```html
<form action="/api/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload image from device
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
  </form>
```

How can I get the same result in Angular 5, so that I have better control over the response and where to direct my app based on that response